# Anime about a female vigilante who fights psychics and robots, and gets turned against by the city she lives in

Tags: story-identification, anime

I don't remember much about this anime because I watched it when I was a child (2005-2008-ish). I remember there was a female who was like a vigilante and she had this sidekick, who was I think a lot younger than her. At the end of the show the city she lives in turns against her, and she becomes a bad guy in the eyes of the city. I remember her getting out the shower and seeing the news about her.

Some more information:

- The anime style is like *Cowboy Bebop* or *Evangelion*
- There was a bit of nudity when she got out the shower
- They did have powers but it was like telekinesis, and some of her opponents were robotic
- The fashion choices weren't bad for the time it came out
- I'd say it aired between 2005-2009, I don't think it was past 2010

Comment: I'm guessing there are probably science fiction or fantasy aspects that you haven't covered here? Does she have powers? Do her opponents? Please check the lists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and more specifically [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) to elicit more details you can [edit] into your question. Like what was the animation style like? Was there adult content? Nudity? Violence? Bad fashion choices?

Comment: ^_^ Sorry... the bit about fashion choices was a standard joke I make when asking questions. It wasn't meant to be a serious query. I do suggest visiting those links for more prompts to follow, and to read the [tour] to learn how to accept an answer. Did the main character have light skin? Dark skin? Do you remember hair color or style?

Comment: For some reasons, this reminds me of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergo_Proxy which came out in 2005-2006 which I never watched.

Comment: Where did you watch it? And did you watch this on TV, or with another media?

Comment: Was the sidekick male or female? And what was the hair colour of the main character?

Comment: Aeon Flux?  There were several versions, animated, live action, movie, etc.